# How do I set the initial values of a typed Map in the constructor when the keys have multiple types

Tags: typescript

I want to create a `Map` where the key can be a `number` or a `string`. I want to initialise it with values in the constructor. Some entries have a `number` key and some have a `string` key.

But I get a typescript error. Is this a TypeScript bug, or am I doing something wrong?

```
type MyMap = Map<string | number, string>;

// Errors, incorrectly?
const myMapWithMixedKeys: MyMap = new Map([
  ['abc', 'String key'],
  [123, 'Number key']
]);

// All fine
myMapWithMixedKeys.set('abcd', 'String key');
myMapWithMixedKeys.set(1234, 'Number key');

const myMapStrings: MyMap = new Map([
  ['abc', 'String key'],
  ['abcd', 'String key']
]);

const myMapNumbers: MyMap = new Map([
  [123, 'Number key'],
  [1234, 'Number key']
]);
```

The error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(iterable: Iterable<readonly [string, string]>): Map<string, string>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '([string, string] | [number, string])[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<readonly [string, string]>'.
      Types of property '[Symbol.iterator]' are incompatible.
        Type '() => IterableIterator<[string, string] | [number, string]>' is not assignable to type '() => Iterator<readonly [string, string], any, undefined>'.
          Type 'IterableIterator<[string, string] | [number, string]>' is not assignable to type 'Iterator<readonly [string, string], any, undefined>'.
            Types of property 'next' are incompatible.
              Type '(...args: [] | [undefined]) => IteratorResult<[string, string] | [number, string], any>' is not assignable to type '(...args: [] | [undefined]) => IteratorResult<readonly [string, string], any>'.
                Type 'IteratorResult<[string, string] | [number, string], any>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<readonly [string, string], any>'.
                  Type 'IteratorYieldResult<[string, string] | [number, string]>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<readonly [string, string], any>'.
                    Type 'IteratorYieldResult<[string, string] | [number, string]>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorYieldResult<readonly [string, string]>'.
                      Type '[string, string] | [number, string]' is not assignable to type 'readonly [string, string]'.
                        Type '[number, string]' is not assignable to type 'readonly [string, string]'.
                          Types of property '0' are incompatible.
                            Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(entries?: readonly (readonly [string, string])[] | null | undefined): Map<string, string>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '([string, string] | [number, string])[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'readonly (readonly [string, string])[]'.
      Type '[string, string] | [number, string]' is not assignable to type 'readonly [string, string]'.
        Type '[number, string]' is not assignable to type 'readonly [string, string]'.ts(2769)
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that TS infer the type of a `new Map()` by its first value.
It happens even you write just `let m = new Map([[1, 1], ['2', 2]])`, without any typing.

(BTW: It happens also in arrays when you write something like `let a = new Array(1, '2')`).

To solve this you should to force TS to understand that the type of the Map is union type. I know two ways to do this:

```
const myMapWithMixedKeys: MyMap = new Map<string | number, string>([
  ['abc', 'String key'],
  [123, 'Number key']
]);
```

Or:

```
const myMapWithMixedKeys: MyMap = new Map([
  ['abc' as string | number, 'String key'],
  [123, 'Number key']
]);
```

See [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/PTAEFECdIe0hYAUAYxgOwM4BdQFsCeAsgIYAOA6gJZYAWhlAHgKYAmA0k-hqALyhpMA7qBKkAFAG0koUBIDkxAEbI5AGlByAylkiU0Ac1ABrTnIC6q6bICMAJgDM6uQDkArrkVNIx02aRmASgBuJCQQUHI4I1BBJgAbOKRUTBwCUSpaemZ2TgxrXn4hETIAHmxdA1AAH353T0h1cr19AD5JK3klFSdtCsMTfHNLRBkJO0cNNw8vH0G-RECQxCT0bDwiMgy6RlYOLlsCgWFRdpHZBWU5UGJuJsqatDqvHp1m2aGO8acp+vf5xdCiHCmmIuCYoD012gxC4SDiTBwxGg+T4R1AAEFofgxNYnLY5ME4QioZADqiipjIDCyq97rVppA2riNPjCYh4YjoPZDhSsTjrrdaYYHk8GiyCUEgA)

EDIT: I found a better solution, IMO.

Instead of:

```
type MyMap = Map<string | number, string>;
```

Write:

```
class MyMap extends Map<string | number, string> { }
```

And now everything works well. See [updated Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeswAdoFMAeAXNA7AJjEsgDwRYBOAlrgObQA+0uArgLYBGaFANNOdToA+aAG9oAXwCwAKFkB6edACCIENABmNNLOAB7XOWhtEKAOpUsAC1hUMafAGk08CAC44p1AF5maAO6exAAUANqy0NChAORgHMDRfNEAypQ09ADWLtEAujwRUQCMAEwAzEkAcuxcFNBZ8LmyOQCUANyysibEFta29k4uEAB0EGhYwbHx+InQKWl0ddltnV49NnYOzq4jY8ElpQAsldXciw3LcjL6hljGXqmCtO5BKNC+uAFwKGEFMXEJSQe6TOuXyMkifymMzmjxBOSaF10BiMXRQVU43GeCGIbz8gRC4XBRTKxwxtXqoN++yOs3RNThCPaMiAA)